# Block.objects.get(id=block_id, 1) get "1" as default if id is null

Tags: django

I'd like to retrieve block from database

```
 block = Block.objects.get(id=block_id, 1)
```

if block_id does not exist, get "1" as default value,

However, it report error:

```
block = Block.objects.get(id=block_id, 1)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

How could I achieve such a functionality?

Comment: You mean the variable does not exists, or is `None`, (those are two different concepts).

Comment: does not exist, @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: you confuse dictionary methods with a class method `objects`. The objects is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check for existence of variable

It is typically *bad* modeling if the variable can not exist. In that case it is better to assign *some* value to it first (for example `None`, or another *dummy value*). We can however use the exception mechanism of Python, like:

```
try:
    temp_block_id = block_id
except NameError:
    temp_block_id = 1
block = Block.objects.get(id=temp_block_id)
```

But as said before, this is an *antipattern*. It is better to assign a value to a variable.

## Shield against `None`

In case the default value is `None` (so it *has* a value), we can use for example a *ternary operator*:

```
block = Block.objects.get(id=block_id if block_id is not None else 1)
```

This assumes that the variable *has* a value. If that is not the case, it will raise a `NameError`.

## Guard against truthiness `False`

Most databases do not use an `id=0`, so we can make the above more elegant, by writing:

block = Block.objects.get(id=**block_id or 1**)

In cases where `block_id` is `None`, `0`, the empty string, or other values with truthiness `False`, it will replace it with `1`. But this again assumes that `block_id` has a value.

Comment: impressive, the expression could be written to argument.